# CSS width x less than width?

Tags: css, width, screen

I'd like to have a navigation bar that's centered on the top of the page, and I'd like the width to be 80px less than the screen width. Is there a way to do this with pure CSS, no javascript? I've seen this done before, but I didn't bother to check the source at the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `margin-left: 40px` and `margin-right: 40px` on the navbar div.

Sample:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body style='padding: 0; margin: 0;'>
    <div style='margin: 0 40px 0 40px; background-color:red;'>CONTENT YAY.</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old question, but if I had to do this right now I'd use `vh` (viewport height) and `vw` (viewport width) units. They're like percentage units but based on the viewport size.

`width: 80vw`

sets your container width to 80% **of the viewport** width.